# Should there be a writing tag or similar?

Tags: discussion, tags

All biologists have to write on biology (papers, thesis etc), and use words and conventions that are unfamiliar to those outside of the subject. Other stack exchanges have created tags like writing or [article writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-writing) to allow for specialist discussion of how to write within their subjects.

I'd argue that writing on biology is no less of a specialist skill, no less difficult or no less important than writing on maths, or any of the other subjects that have these tags.

As a result I'd like to see a tag created to allow for this kind of specialized discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The poster writes:

> “…I'd like to see a tag created to allow…”

He seems to be making the common mistake of thinking that tags determine whether a question is on topic, i.e. if a tag exists that can be given to a question it is on topic. This is *not* the case. The scope of this site is defined on the first page of the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour):

> “we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about biology.”

This is expanded in the Help section under [What Topics can I ask about here?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where the following are listed:

- general questions about biological concepts
- questions about the
  biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
- questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

So if you want to expand the scope of this site to cover writing, that is what you should request, but I would say it does not fit with the current idea of the site and is unlikely to be supported.

Moreover there do exist three SE sites on which you can ask specific questions about the use of English. [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com)  deals with general questions for those non-native speakers who are not yet proficient in English. [Stack Exchange English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com) accepts questions by fluent speakers on a variety of topics, including technical English. However neither of these sites will accept questions that are requests for comments on your writing (so-called proof-reading questions). There is also a [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) (currently in beta) which accepts questions on technical writing.